# Downloading contextual GIS layer using QGIS

Tags: wms

I am using QGIS 3.16 and I want to use a raster layer for analysis. The layer is available only through WMS service. I want to use the raster image with SCP tool for further processing and analysis.

I am able to save the layer but with a reduced resolution. Moreover, the information regarding the band is missing in the exported image.
The wms service is https://bhuvan-vec2.nrsc.gov.in/bhuvan/wms and the layer is lulc:WB_LULC50K_0506